# Redirect client script to a record type

Tags: javascript, netsuite, clientscript

How do I get redirected to a record type after executing a command in a client script. Explaining better, I'm in a client script, and after clicking a button, a new record is generated in another record type, and I want to be redirected there.

Thank you

I need to leave this page after performing the procedures, and be redirected to the record I just created

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share code examples and and error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newType = <NetSuite ID of record type>;

  // making new record code

var newId = newRecord.save();

  // performing the procedures

// Requires the N/url module
var output = url.resolveRecord({
    recordType: newType,
    recordId: newId,
    isEditMode: true
});

window.location.replace(output);
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you very much. Actually I was wrong in the last statement, the window.location ... but now it worked. Thank you!